# This page can't be displayed in VS page inspector

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express, page-inspector

I have a project which would load up fine locally until I set SSL to true. I have updated the url in the project properties however when I try to run the project or view web pages in page inspector I get the "This page can't be displayed" message.

I have uninstalled and re-installed IIS Express to see if that worked but no joy

Any tips wold be very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Kevin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis). I scrolled down to use the IIS Manager. Hope others find this useful

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If you view the project's properties you will see 2 URLs, an SSL URL and a plain URL. Make sure that the SSL URL is being used by default.

[image]